# Azure and file not found

Tags: php, azure

I have recently returned to an azure project and I have a file which I know is there and had worked fine previously. Now when linking to the file I am getting a firefox file not found error (not a code 500 error!) and asking me if I have the case of my filename correct.

For reference it is a php application.

I do appreciate people's suggestions

Comment: Are you able to obtain the directory listing on the server physically and can you verify the file still exists?

Comment: Yes, Its there physically, Im working in development

Comment: Is only that file not working or are other files not working, too? And as it's windows, have you already rebooted everything?

Comment: Its an azure app so its deployed through the development fabric. Its not giving a 404 error, its firefox saying that it cant see the server (as if there was no internet connection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that by using safari instead of firefox the appfabric is returning valuable debug information which firefox chooses to keep a secret. Thanks firefox

Answer (score 0):

Check file permissions. If the file is restricted it could be giving an error

Comment: the file has the same permissions as other files which do compute